# Display Image depending on data or no data present in mysql table

Tags: php

I have a table where there is text  entered by the user or no text entered.  When the table is displayed I currently have a clickable icon that pops open a box displaying the data whether there is any data or not.  I would like the clickable icon to indicate whether or not there is a value present...  I have this...sort of... with another field already but it was easier because the data value was either Yes or No..see below

```
<td align=\"center\"><img src=backgrounds/" . $rows['fixed'] . ".png></td>
```

if yes then the yes.png icon is displayed, if no then the no.png icon is displayed.
Here is what I currently have for the info field

```
<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"page.html\" target=\"popup\"
 onClick=\"wopen('info_form.php?id=$rows[id]', 'popup', 400, 200); return false;\"><img src=\"backgrounds/info4.png\" border=\"0\"></a></td>
```

is there anyway to do what I want and have similar to the yes no field? I could have a default value in the default field of no and then use a no.png but how would I do a value of not no then use  "something other than no".png??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a check on the $row['fixed'] to see if there is any value present.

```
<?php if($rows['fixed']!=''){?>
     <td align=\"center\"><img src=backgrounds/" . $rows['fixed'] . ".png></td>
<?php }else{?>
     something else?
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I see what you are saying however it's a little more complex, the row you indicated 'fixed' works fine, it's for the other bit of code I indicated below, currently saying <img src=\"backgrounds/info4.png\" border=\"0\">  , this is where I wan the either or .png displayed, it relates to the $rows['info']...with the popup box.

Comment: In here is where I want to change the <img src=\"backgrounds/info4.png\" border=\"0\"> info4.png to be something like no.png if I make the default value No in my table but if somebody eneters some sort of free hand data then I need an icon that is called "not no".png , however that's not quite possible.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I currently modified it to be  :::<img src=backgrounds/" . $rows['info'] . ".png border=\"0\">    :::